# "Сколько ещё ждать..."

Tags: падежи

Всегда употребляю "ждать" с родительным падежом, например, "жду автобуса, поезда". Но поймал себя на том, что говорю иначе в следующем выражении:

> Сколько ещё ждать *этот поезд!*

И не могу понять, почему так получается. То ли я его как будто одушевляю в уме, то ли с местоимением "этот" сложнее сказать в родительном падеже.

Что вы по этому поводу думаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз десять уже обсасывали. Лень даже искать.

https://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

С глаголом "ждать" (и некоторыми другими) винительный падеж обычно соответствует конкретному объекту ("жду вот тот трамвай, он уже отъехал от предыдущей обстановки"), родительный - общему ("жду любого трамвая, чтобы только уехать"). Другие случаи разделения функций между родительным и винительным (в т. ч. и при глаголах "ждательной группы") - посмотрите по ссылке.
А еще можете посмотреть т. н. "ждательный падеж".

Comment: Спасибо, behomethus!